# Работа с JobIntentService в kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Как мне сделать так, чтобы выводилось сообщение так как это делают программы, когда например висят как сервис и оповещают о чем нибудь в уведомлениях? Я новичок в разработке для android и на kotlin. Я сделал рабочий пример, с тостами, но они не выводятся и я понимаю что не так делаю, но как надо правильно? вот код.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.xverizex.service

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import com.xverizex.service.enqueueWork

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val intent = Intent(this, SimpleJobIntentService::class.java)
        enqueueWork(this, intent)

    }
}
```

**SimpleJobIntentService.kt**

```
package com.xverizex.service

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.os.ResultReceiver
import android.widget.ThemedSpinnerAdapter
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.JobIntentService
val JOB_ID : Int = 1000;

fun enqueueWork(context: Context, work: Intent) {
    JobIntentService.enqueueWork(context, SimpleJobIntentService::class.java, JOB_ID, work)
}

class SimpleJobIntentService : JobIntentService() {

    override fun onHandleWork(intent: Intent) {
        toast ("Executing: back")
        for ( i in 0 .. 10 ){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000)
            } catch (ex : InterruptedException) {

            }
        }
        toast("end 10 seconds")
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        toast("All work complete")
    }

    var handler = Looper.getMainLooper()

    fun toast (text : CharSequence) {
        Looper.prepare()
        handler.run {
            Toast.makeText(this@SimpleJobIntentService, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        Looper.loop()
    }

}
```

Можно конечно распаковать apk какой нибудь программы, и посмотреть smali код, но это надо привыкнуть к этому коду и ещё найти то что нужно среди такой большой кучи кода.

Comment: Toast.makeText(this@SimpleJobIntentService, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

Answer (score 0):

**Во 1:**

Исправьте функцию:

```
fun toast (text : CharSequence) {
        Looper.prepare()
        handler.run {
            Toast.makeText(this@SimpleJobIntentService, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        }
        Looper.loop()
    }
```

на:

```
fun toast (text : CharSequence) {
        Looper.prepare()
        handler.run {
            Toast.makeText(this@SimpleJobIntentService, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        Looper.loop()
    }
```

**Во 2:**
Прочитайте про жизненный цикл приложения на Android:

https://metanit.com/java/android/2.1.php

Comment: toast("end 10 seconds") не выводиться после цикла? это из-за Looper?